# What is the penalty if you forget to pick in a professional match?

Tags: league-of-legends, competitive-gaming

In League of Legends pro-scene, if you don't pick a champion in the allowed time, what would happen?

We sometimes see a forgotten ban, that just means that you lose that ban; and in normal play the lobby would be dissolved and everybody returns to the queue.

But in professional play, what would happen?

What is the penalty if you don't pick your champion in a professional match?

Comment: Well for starters, you feel like an idiot. Then Reddit makes fun of you for the next three years until they finally get tired of their dead-horse meme beating.

Comment: You have to play as Teemo.

Comment: You probably just get -3lp on the tournament realm.

Comment: Asked the same thing on the forums, let's see what will be the answer. https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/esports/OuPwPaBa-what-is-the-penalty-if-you-forget-to-pick-in-a-professional-match

Comment: Thrown it on reddit too, I really wonder what would happen. https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/6amygj/what_is_the_penalty_if_you_forget_to_pick_in_a/

Comment: The player can probably just claim he clicked but nothing happened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there is no official ruling about that particular scenario, but Section 7.7 in [the rulebook](https://esports-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/production/files/rules/EU_Rulebook.pdf) has all the rules about the pick and ban phase.

Comment: You are right, there is no rule regarding if a person fails to pick his champion. There's a rule about a mispick tho. Interesting